# Outlook Add-In Icon Not Showing

Tags: outlook, manifest, office-addins

For some reason, when I load the manifest file into Outlook, the default icon is displaying for my Outlook add-in.  The add-in is being hosted internally at our organization—would that cause this issue?

Below I have selected the pertinent sections of my manifest file.  Please let me know if any other information is needed.  Any help would be appreciated.

Manifest hosts:

```
<Hosts>
        <Host xsi:type="MailHost">
            <DesktopFormFactor>
                <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="AppointmentOrganizerCommandSurface">
                    <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
                        <Group id="msgReadGroup">
                            <Label resid="groupLabel" />
                            <Control xsi:type="Button" id="msgReadOpenPaneButton">
                                <Label resid="paneAppointmentButtonLabel" />
                                <Supertip>
                                    <Title resid="paneCreateAptSuperTipTitle" />
                                    <Description resid="paneCreateAptTipDescription" />
                                </Supertip>
                                <Icon>
                                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="icon16" />
                                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="icon32" />
                                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="icon80" />
                                </Icon>
                                <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                                    <SourceLocation resid="appointmentCreatePaneURL" />
                                </Action>
                            </Control>
                        </Group>
                    </OfficeTab>
                </ExtensionPoint>
            </DesktopFormFactor>
        </Host>
    </Hosts>
```

Manifest resources:

```
<Resources>
        ...
        <bt:Images>
            <bt:Image id="icon16" DefaultValue="https://intranet-domain.com/assets/icon-16.png" />
            <bt:Image id="icon32" DefaultValue="https://intranet-domain.com/assets/icon-32.png" />
            <bt:Image id="icon80" DefaultValue="https://intranet-domain.com/assets/icon-80.png" />
        </bt:Images>
        ...
</Resources>
```

Comment: Any luck on this issue?

Comment: I'm having this issue too. Was this resolved? I have a feeling its a header issue.

Comment: Same issue here..